# ruby quick string subset analysis

Tags: ruby

I have two strings:

```
"0123"
"023"
```

I want to be able to show that '0', '2' and '3' exist in "0123", I have tried arrays, sets, and substring methods on the string, with no avail.

Is there some way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Array intersection ([`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26)):

```
a = '0123'.chars
b = '023'.chars

intersections = a & b
```

Comment: I chose this answer instead as it appears more efficient.

Comment: I suggest to use `chars` instead of `split('')` since it is clearer and faster.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about the two strings as arrays and then as sets and then trying to get the difference between them.
But you don't want the difference you want the similarities, so that's why the `!` is before the [include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).

```
a.split("").reject{|x| !"023".split("").include?(x)}
```

This could then further be refined to be a bit more readable

```
first_string = "0123".split("")
second_string = "023".split("")

first_string.reject{ |x| !second_string.include?(x) }
```

and lastly if you want something more Ruby-esque you could use [intersections](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26).

```
result = first_string & second_string
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to do this: if a.split("").reject{|x| !"#{b}".split("").include?(x)}.join == b ... end

Answer (score 0):

This returns whether all chars of one string are present in the second, by iterating over each byte-value of the needed string and checking if the character-value is present in the string to check, joining the result to a string and comparing this with the needed string to return true or false.

```
to_check = '0123'
to_check2 = '9123'
needed = '023'

p needed.each_byte.map{|c|to_check[c.chr]}.join == needed #true
p needed.each_byte.map{|c|to_check2[c.chr]}.join == needed #false
```

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly.

```
matches = []
"023".each_char { |c| matches << c if "0123".index(c) }

p matches # Output ["0", "2", "3"]
```